# How can I check an email address has been registered or not on the firebase auth, like as the firebaseui does it?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

## The login sequence of the firebaseui.

The login sequence starts with only an email address.

[image]

In case the address has been registered to the firebase, login will continue.

[image]

If not added, a new account will be created.

[image]

## My Question

How can I check an email address that has been registered or not on the firebase auth, as the firebaseui does it?
I'm looking for the appropriate API to check the email address if it has been added or not. I've searched on the 
 document [firebase. auth. Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth?), but I can't find it.
I've tried the `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, "")` with expect to get the error **auth/user-not-found**, but I've get **auth/wrong-password**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following method, from the docs:

> `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`
>
> `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email: string): Promise<Array<string>>`
>
> Gets the list of possible sign in methods for the given email address. This is useful to differentiate methods of sign-in for the same provider, eg. EmailAuthProvider which has 2 methods of sign-in, email/password and email/link.
>
> Error Codes
>
> auth/invalid-email
>   Thrown if the email address is not valid.
>
> Parameters
>
> `email: string`
>
> `Returns Promise<Array<string>>`

This will return an error if the email is not registered

Comment: Thank you peter! I've tried it and I can get a blank list for the email which is not registered. I will use this API, thank you!